# Hilo no permite iniciar un service

Tags: android, android-studio, hilos, android-service

He estado probando a iniciar un service para que me lleve a cabo una tarea aún cuando la aplicación sea destruida, conseguí que el service fuese aunque la app se cerraba debido a esto:

> *I/Choreographer: Skipped 1200 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.*

Como saturaba demasiado el hilo principal intenté delegar esta tarea en un hilo secundario pero este en cambio no permite iniciar el service debido a que este no hereda de Service.

El error que produce el LogCat:

> *Intent prueba = new Intent(this, serviceName.class);
> ^
> constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
> (argument mismatch; hiloService cannot be converted to String)
> constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
> (argument mismatch; hiloService cannot be converted to Context)*

Esta es la clase donde inicio el nuevo hilo:

```
public void battleFinal(View view){
    hiloService thread = new hiloService(secTotal,itemList);
    thread.start();

    Intent battleFinal = new Intent(this, disputa_nombres.class);
    battleFinal.putExtra("lista",itemList);
    battleFinal.putExtra("segundos",secTotal);
    startActivity(battleFinal);


}
```

Esta es la clase del nuevo hilo:

```
public class hiloService extends Thread {
// @Override
private int sec;
private ArrayList<String> nameList;

public hiloService(int sec,ArrayList<String> nameList) {
    this.sec = sec;
    this.nameList = nameList;
}
public void run() {
    Intent prueba = new Intent(this, serviceName.class);
    prueba.putExtra("lista",nameList);
    prueba.putExtra("segundos",sec);
    startService(prueba);
}
```

}

Esta es la clase del Service:

```
 public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     itemList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("lista");

    int firstNum;
    int secNum;

    while (itemList.size() > 1) {

        try {
            //  TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(8);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){}
        //NUMERO RANDON
       firstNum = (int) (Math.random() * itemList.size());
        do{
            secNum = (int) (Math.random() * itemList.size());
        }while(secNum == firstNum);
       // sendNotification(String.valueOf(firstNum));

       
        System.out.println(itemList.get(secNum)+" ha vencido a " +itemList.get(firstNum));

        itemList.remove(firstNum);
 
        if(itemList.size() == 1){
      
        }
      //  sendNotification("Hola");
        
    }

    System.out.println("El tamaño de la lista es "+ itemList.size()+" Y el ganador es : "+itemList.get(0));
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema? Hay otras soluciones más fáciles para esta problemática?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

revisa WorkManager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics?hl=es-419 Lee  con calma eso, yo queria usar un service igual que tu, y termine usando esto y va de maravillas